# Por que acontece esse loop infinito?

Tags: c, loop, while

Fiz esse código mas fica dando loop infinito e não consigo arrumar...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
int x, z;

        while("x=100; x!=65; x-=5"){
            z=x*x;
            printf("%d --> %d\n", x, z);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenho quase certeza que é devido as aspas:

```
"x=100; x!=65; x-=5"
```

Remova-as:

```
 while(x=100; x!=65; x-=5){
```

valores entre aspas em C são `char *`, ou seja você não passou as variáveis, mas sim `char`, e pro loop quebrar precisa passar um valor como "`false`", todavia o while não funciona com `;`, provavelmente você quer usar o `for`:

```
for (x=100; x!=65; x-=5){
    z=x*x;
    printf("%d --> %d\n", x, z);
}
```

Ou se for o `while` pode usar assim:

```
x=100;

while (x!=65){
    z=x*x;
    printf("%d --> %d\n", x, z);
    x-=5;
}
```

Comment: Já tentei porem ele da erro na hora de compilar e fica pedindo pra por um ) depois do (x=100

6 15 [Error] expected ')' before ';' token

Comment: @EvelynnDelRey editei a resposta.

Comment: Oque você me enviou deu certo, mas tipo a maioria da minha turma fez o x=100; e x-=5; dentro do while(), como ficaria ? queria saber oque eu fiz de errado ...

Comment: @EvelynnDelRey isso até aonde sei não existe em `C`, você deve ter feito confusão. Documentação MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/y1tscb5y.aspx

Comment: provavelmente man, brigadão pela ajuda <3